# SignalR - Clients.All methods send to wrong page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr, signals

I have problem with undarstand SignalR hubs.
I have one class with Hub.
I have two pages in my application which are connected to same hub.

When i call method like : Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message, time, "")
Only method (script) from Page1 is running /why?

If i delete this method from Page1 nothing happed...

Screenshot with problem:
https://ibb.co/nLs7jDc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaKqh.png)

FINALLY SOLVED. (so issue was in method declaration):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyPqL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your call to start() below the messageReceived handler method.

> Before you can establish a connection, you have to create a connection object, create a proxy, and register event handlers for methods that can be called from the server. When the proxy and event handlers are set up, establish the connection by calling the start method.

How to establish a connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

```
$(function(){
    var logger = $.connection.logHub;
    $.connection.hub.error(function(error){});
    logger.client.messageReceived = function(){};
    $.connection.start();
});
```